# Update all data of model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

For example we have:

```
class PublicLibrary  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end


class Book  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :public_library
end
```

If we want do update all books in PublicLibrary, we can add to PublicLibrary model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :books, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if=>:all_blank
```

And now we can do something like this

```
library=PublicLibrary.find(ID)
library.update_attributes(:books_attributes=>{<bunch of books here>})
```

And all related books will be updated, some books'll be removed and some new books will be inserted in table books

Now I have some model Book, that doesn't have relation with PublicLibrary:

```
class Book  < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have an admin panel that show all books in one big-big table and want to update/delete/insert new books just by one click, so I want something like

```
Book.bulk_update({...books...})
```

Or working with subset (don't sure is I really need it, but if we can do that...why not to know how?)

```
books_to_update=Book.where(...).bulk_update({...books...})
```

Of course Book may have some nested models.

Do you have any ideas?
P.S. Currently I have only idea of having some parent and do update for it...

Comment: Unfortunately ActiveRecord can't do everything and, whilst I could be wrong, I don't think what you're asking for is possible.  I've got my own gripe about AR making it tough to work with polymorphs + STI, so I know how you feel!

However, it shouldn't be too difficult to write some code that iterates through the hash and creates/updates/destroys as appropriate.  You could make it into a gem that extends the functionality of ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

your {...books...} hash either has multiple books in it for which you want

```
books.each { |id, book| Book.find(id).update_attributes(book) }
```

or you want to do a real bulk update (meaning same update to all books in action)
then you can use http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: Yeah, I know it. Your solution doesn't do what i need. I need update+delete+insert different data in **one** query to **activeRecord** (I specially showed the example of working with nested attributes).

Sure I can do it by myself, but if rails can do it for nested attributes, maybe it can do the work for bunch of data that doesn't have some parent?